# AngularJS: How to send parameter with $location.path()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, location

I'm trying to create redirection call in controller with some numeric parameter or argument but I'm failded. I'm using this code

```
$location.path('/tastlist/:$rootScope.job_id');
```

also i'ave tried

```
$location.path("/tastlist/",$rootScope.job_id');
```

My route is as follows:

```
$routeProvider.when('/tastlist/:job_id', {templateUrl: 'partials/list-task.html', controller: 'tasklistCtrl'});
```

Route is working well in my html for this code:

```
<a ng-click="go('/tastlist/' + job.id)">back to task list</a>
```

I want to create automatic redirection in controller via
`$location.path()` or via anyother. Please help me out for this..

Answer (score 3):

Your second try is almost right

```
$location.path("/tastlist/" + $rootScope.job_id);
```

you are building the url with the actual value you want to set.
if you'd do

```
 $location.path("/tastlist/4");
```

`job_id` in $stateParams would get set to 4

Comment: Thanks bro. You earned my respect. It is now working. Dont forget to upvote my question too.